# Search if a string has two specific words

Tags: r, grepl

How do I search if a column of strings has these two words "medication" and "infant" anywhere in the sentence ?

For example if the column contains strings such as

```
  ID       Col1
  1        Quick Brown fox medication
  2        Brown fox infant
  3        Quick medication fox infant
```

The expected results should be just row with ID 3

```
 ID       Col1
  3        Quick medication fox infant
```

I have tried `str_detect` and that did not work, so any suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: @zx8754, nope, order does not matter. The words can be anywhere in the sentence in any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Base R Approach**

---

```
df[with(df, grepl("infant", Col1) & grepl("medication", Col1)),]
```

It is simple and easy to follow.

```
df <-  data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), Col1=c('Quick Brown fox medication',
                                      'Brown fox infant',
                                      'Quick medication fox infant'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `grepl` with two positive lookaheads:

```r
regex <- "(?=.*\\bmedication\\b)(?=.*\\binfant\\b).*"
df[grepl(regex, df$Col1, perl=TRUE), ]

  ID                        Col1
3  3 Quick medication fox infant
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID=c(1,2,3),
    Col1=c("Quick Brown fox medication", "Brown fox infant",
           "Quick medication fox infant")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`grepl` and `filter` can help:

```
df <-  data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), Col1=c('Quick Brown fox medication',
                                      'Brown fox infant',
                                      'Quick medication fox infant'))
```

```
dplyr::filter(df,grepl("medication",Col1) &
                 grepl("infant",Col1))
```

**Output**

```
  id                        Col1
1  3 Quick medication fox infant
```